# Best practice for using main function

Tags: python

For the best use of:

`if __name__ == "__main__"` ,

what is the best?

Option 1: Create a class that runs the application and then create an instance of that class like:

```py
class Application():
    #main code goes here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
```

Option 2. Or put the main code in a main function and then call that function:

```py
def main():
    #do all the main stuff

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

How should I proceed?

Edit: ok, I got the subjective and personal aspects in this questions. Also, I´ve found a very interesting article here: https://realpython.com/python-main-function/
Helped a lot

Comment: depends if you want a singleton object or a main function.

Comment: note that "Best practice" questions are usually closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre best-practise is not always subjective in python given the documentation and PEP guidance

Comment: True, Chris. Not here, though. But personally, I always create a big singleton object so I can use "global" variables without using `global`, just by defining instance or class variables of the big singleton class.

Comment: very opinion based, but I'd always do whatever is easiest/most obvious given all the other constraints you're working with.  if it's a small script put code directly under the `if` statement, if it's getting more complicated/want some reuse/easier debugging move code into a `main()` function, if you have an Application object, feel free to put an entry point in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to pick, I'd say that the best practice for using the `__main__` would be:

```
class Application():
    #main code goes here

def main():
    app = Application()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is pretty subjective but I usually would use the above code because that is how I typically see it formatted in python pre-installed modules (eg. turtledemo - `__main__.py`)

I hope this helps!

Comment: **very** subjective!  that demo is just working around their GUI/event loop infrastructure